# How to add app on Notification slider (iOS5)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

How is it possible to add your app on notification slider on ios5, and possibly update data at some interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it for free if you already support notifications. If you would like to learn more about notifications, and notification center, see apple's docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html

Also, in order to get your app listed on your device in Notification Center, go to Settings -> Notifications, and see the list under Notification Center.

Comment: I do know about NotificationCenter but I was not sure if I can add it like Yahoo has done. Yahoo has made it like a Widget which permanently stays in the notification slider in iPhone 4S.

Comment: Joy, it will only be possible to have the notifications supported like most other apps in the iOS notification center list (see the Settings->Notifications), but unless you have some kind of insider deal with Apple (or create something Apple loves so much they agree to include it), I think you'll not be getting a widget in Apple's Notification Center that is customized like the "Yahoo" ones. (I'm assuming you're referring to the weather and stock apps).

Comment: @Joy unless you go the jailbreak way... But your app will not be accepted on the App Store.

Comment: @icnivad yes, I am referring to Yahoo Weather App. I believe that Apple needs to being Widget feature to all the developers, as they provided to Yahoo for Weather Widget. Hopefully in near future :)

Comment: @fbernardo I am a developer, so jailbreak option is not for me. I want my apps to publish on the Apple app market.

Comment: @Joy So, only the developers of apps published on the App Store count as developers? Anyway, then you have no option, you can close the question.

Comment: @Joy, you can check mark my answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @fbernardo no...there are many other developers too but as far as I know, the app market for jailbroken phone provides free apps and even if not I am not looking for any kind of troubles with apple.

Comment: @icnivad  I was unable to vote app. Stackoverflow is not allowing